# Почему может неправильно считаться сумма вещественных чисел?

Tags: c++

Задание:
Даны три действительных числа: a, b, c. Проверьте, выполняется ли равенство a+b=c.

Формат выходных данных:
Если равенство выполняется, выведите «YES», если не выполняется, выведите «NO».

В чем моя ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
long double a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
if (a + b == c){
cout << "YES";
}
else
cout << "NO";
return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если год назад дан ответ на похожий вопрос , то   это не делает данный вопрос дубликатом. Я отмечаю как полезный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут не столько ошибка, сколько незнание представления чисел с [плавающей точкой](http://digteh.ru/proc/float/) в компьютере. 
Не вдаваясь сильно в теорию, при инициализации нового значения `double` или `float`, есть вероятность, что вы присвоите не `0.3`, а `0.300000000000001`. Ну и выходит проблема при сравнении.

В случае с С++, можно воспользоваться следующей фичей : `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` - это [следующее число](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) после 1.0.

Ну и пример использования в коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool compare(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(a - b) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}

int main(){
    double a,b,c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if (compare(a + b, c)) 
        cout << "YES";
    else
        cout << "NO";
}
```

Comment: это самое маленькое число близкому нулю, а не после 1.0